# Object is not legal as a SQL literal value

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

Long time reader, first time poster, please be gentle.

I've been working on a web app using Flask and SQLAlchemy that allows users to review and comment on MMA fights. I have a list of fights in a SQL table appropriately named "fights" and I'm trying to use dynamic routing to filter through the data. I have a list of all the fights on one route like so:

```
    @app.route('/ufc251')
    @login_required
    def ufc251():
        return render_template('ufc251.html', fights=Fight.query.all())
```

which helped me make a slick page with all the fights listed, and then made another route for info on individual fights like so:

```
     @app.route('/fight/<int:id>')
     @login_required
     def fight(id):
         id = Fight.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
         return render_template('fight.html')
```

so far, so good. If I click on a fight from the main page i get sent to a url fightsite/fights/<fight_id>, which is perfect. The problem that I'm having is that I can't for the life of me figure out how to call the data from the row for a single fight. If i change my route to:

```
    @app.route('/fight/<int:id>')
    @login_required
    def fight(id):
         id = Fight.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
         return render_template('fight.html', fight=Fight.query.filter_by(id=id).first())
```

I get the error

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Object <Fight 1> is not legal as a SQL literal value

but if i give id a value (i.e. id=1) it will display the data from the first row in my fights table, so i feel like the problem is in the (id=id) part, but after hours of scouring the internet, I can't seem to find a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. And yes, I've read the other StackOverflow article on this subject, however the answer doesn't seem to apply to this situation.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, however I decided I'd leave the question in case anybody else has this issue.

i changed:

```
    @app.route('/fight/<int:id>')
    @login_required
    def fight(id):
       id = Fight.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
       return render_template('fight.html', fight=Fight.query.filter_by(id=id).first())
```

to:

```
 @app.route('/fight/<int:id>')
 @login_required
 def fight(id):
      id = Fight.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
      return render_template('fight.html', fight=Fight.query.filter_by(id=id.id).first())
```

because initially it was passing the argument 'fight_1' instead of just '1'. I hope nobody else has to spend this long trying to solve the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

The use of `id` to hold a Fight confuses things. Then there's the double query when one would suffice.

Consider changing

```
 id = Fight.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
 return render_template('fight.html', fight=Fight.query.filter_by(id=id).first())
```

to

```
fight = Fight.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
return render_template('fight.html', fight=fight)
```